Oracle BI data exceeded leads to timeout error
I've created an analysis in the Oracle R&A tool using data from Oracle subject areas'. However, when the analysis exceeds 100,001 records, I encounter an error in the real data production. What are the best practices to prevent or handle this issue? considering that I do not have the database access.
I attempted to filter the data by date, but the tool still recognizes it as exceeding the limit. My expectation is to retrieve all the data, even if it takes longer.
